# Can't set Kafka retention policy to both compact and delete

Tags: apache-kafka

According to the below links I'm supposed to be able to set the `retention.policy` value to `"compact,delete"`.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4015

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-71%3A+Enable+log+compaction+and+deletion+to+co-exist

However when I try to alter the retention policy by running:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper $KAFKAZKHOSTS  --entity-type
 topics --alter --add-config cleanup.policy=compact,delete --entity-name topicname
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
requirement failed: Invalid entity config: all configs to be added must be in the format "key=val".
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`--add-config cleanup.policy=[compact,delete]`

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in explanation and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Comment: at the kafka offical  guides, http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs, log.cleanup.policy is a type of list,  and list is defined like []

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap a config in quotes: `--add-config 'cleanup.policy=compact,delete'`

Comment: That is not working for the alter command. I tried both: --add-config 'cleanup.policy=compact,delete'  AND --add-config cleanup.policy='compact,delete'

Comment: bin/kafka-topics.sh --topic <topic-name> --partitions 10 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --config 'cleanup.policy=compact,delete' --create

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when you first create the topic you can set the policy to both compact and delete but you can't alter it after the fact.

Comment: That's not correct. You can alter this configuration even if the topic has already been created. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a value for the cleanup policy. For example, if you want to set it to 7 days then you should provide the configuration  `cleanup.policy=compact,delete.retention.ms=604800000`.

Now the full command becomes as follows:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper $KAFKAZKHOSTS --entity-type topics --alter --add-config cleanup.policy=compact,delete.retention.ms=604800000 --entity-name topicname
```

Comment: This is not correct answer. This command sets `cleanup.policy=compact` and parameter `delete.retention.ms=604800000`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `,` character is a splitter for the command line tool, you have to tell it that the multiple value belong to the `cleanup.policy` property. Also, you will need to wrap the list of values with single quotes `'` so that the bash or zsh shell doesn't interpret them as it's own replacement.

What worked for me was:

```
--add-config cleanup.policy='[compact,delete]'
```